# trying to create a 2 step code "if statement"

Tags: php, if-statement

i am trying to add a if statement to the following code, just need clarification to see if it will do the right job.

```
Order #: <? echo $ORDERID?><br />
<br />
Pick-Up Date: <? echo $MYPICKUP?><br />
Comments: <? echo $COMMENTS?><br /><br />        
<? echo $CART?><br />
Order total: $<? echo $GRANDTOTAL?><br />
Payment Method: <? echo $PAYMETHOD?></span><span class="TextB"><br />
```

trying to add Shipping & Handling: in there with the result being :

```
<?php
$paypal = 'paypal';
$check = 'check';

if ($paymethod == $paypal)
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = $GRANDTOTAL * .045";
}
    elseif ($paymethod == $check)
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = 0";
}
?>
```

but my question is, will the shipping and handling amount show up when the option is chosen?

Comment: What happens when you choose the option?

Comment: yes i tried the code and nothing shows up

Comment: Variable names are case sensitive, so `$paymethod` is not the same as `$PAYMETHOD`.

Comment: $PAYMETHOD != $paymethod variable in PHP case sensitivity
and `"Shipping & Handling = $GRANDTOTAL * .045";` must be `"Shipping & Handling = ".($GRANDTOTAL * .045);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure `$paymethod` is not `$PAYMETHOD`, it is case sensitive.
and make sure the `$paymethod` must equals `paypal` or `check`, it is also case sensitive.

Comment: this one worked, but only thing it didnt calculate the $GRANDTOTAL*.045 all it did was mention it again.

Comment: you need change `"Shipping & Handling = {$GRANDTOTAL * .045}"` to `'Shipping & Handling = ' . $GRANDTOTAL * .045`

Comment: that part picks up the fee awesome, but now how do i add the amount from shipping & handling to the grandtotal amount?

Comment: so, you want make grandtotal equals original grandtotal add shipping & handling?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the option for paymentmethod is chosen as paypal it will echo "Shipping & Handling = $GRANDTOTAL * .045" and if it is check, it will echo "Shipping & Handling = 0"

Comment: i find this answer shining as a comment tho

Comment: would the code be like this then? Order #: <? echo $ORDERID?><br />
<br />
Pick-Up Date: <? echo $MYPICKUP?><br />
Comments: <? echo $COMMENTS?><br /><br />        
<? echo $CART?><br />
<?php
$paypal = 'paypal';
$check = 'check';

if ($PAYMETHOD == $paypal)
{
 echo "Shipping & Handling = $GRANDTOTAL * .045";
}
 elseif ($paymethod == $check)
{
 echo "Shipping & Handling = 0";
}
?>
Order total: $<? echo $GRANDTOTAL?><br />
Payment Method: <? echo $PAYMETHOD?></span><span class="TextB"><br />

Answer (score 0):

**Make it like this:**

```
<?php
$paypal = 'paypal';
$check  = 'check';

if ($paymethod == $paypal)
    echo "Shipping & Handling =". $GRANDTOTAL * .045;

elseif ($paymethod == $check)
    echo "Shipping & Handling = 0";

else
echo "Invalid parameter.";
?>
```

If you donot want to calculate the Shipping & Handling make the above statement like this:

```
echo "Shipping & Handling = $GRANDTOTAL * .045";
```