# Adding shipping and handling amount to total in an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to add the the shipping and handling amount to `$grandtotal` in the `if` statement:

```
Order #: <? echo $ORDERID?><br />
<br />
Pick-Up Date: <? echo $MYPICKUP?><br />
Comments: <? echo $COMMENTS?><br /><br />  
<?php
$paypal = 'paypal';
$check = 'check';

if ($PAYMETHOD == $paypal)
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = ".($GRANDTOTAL * .045);
}
    elseif ($PAYMETHOD == $check)
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = 0";
}
?><br />

Grand Total: $<? echo $GRANDTOTAL?><br />
Payment Method: <? echo $PAYMETHOD?></span><span class="TextB"><br />
```

Do I need to define more variables to do this?

Comment: What difference is there between this question and [**your other question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371013/trying-to-create-a-2-step-code-if-statement)?

Comment: And where are you defining `$PAYMETHOD`?

Comment: difference is other question was the if statement, this one is, if there is a way or how can i make it like this for example <? echo $GRANDTOTAL + $SUBTOTAL?> which the subtotal would be shipping and handling or what variable would i use to classify the if function of the shipping and handling?

Comment: You need to define `less` variables to do this. `$paypal="paypal"; if ($PAYMETHOD == $paypal)
` can be if `($PAYMETHOD == "paypal")`

Comment: $ORDERID=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"ORDERID");
$CART=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"CART");
$ORDERTOTAL=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"PRICE");
$CUSTOMER=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"CUSTOMER");
$PAYMETHOD=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"PAYMETHOD");
$PAID=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"PAID");
$MYPICKUP=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"PICKUPDATE");
$COMMENTS=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"COMMENTS");
$GRANDTOTAL=$ORDERTOTAL;

Comment: the if statement works, just trying to figure out how to add the fee i get (the value) to the grandtotal, as of right now it just shows the fee, then the grand total shows by itself nothing is beging added.

Comment: @user2705751 and where is `$SUBTOTAL` defined? Is it your `($GRANDTOTAL * .045)` ?

Comment: @user2705751 This is basic mathematics and accounting stuff. You first need to have a `sub-total` multiplied by your `.045` and assign a variable to it, then add it up after. A `grand` total is the actual amount someone will pay. You're confusing it with sub-total. It's like "The grand total is $40, oh... and there's tax on top of that". ahem..if someone at a store were to tell me that, they will have lost a sale.

Comment: @user2705751 I suggest you change your `$GRANDTOTAL` to `$SUBTOTAL` and your `$ORDERTOTAL` to `$GRANDTOTAL`, because that my friend in "business", is the way it's done. Your `$SUBTOTAL` is the initial price, then comes the tax if there is some, then comes the shipping price. Add those 3 up and you now have a **"GRAND TOTAL"**. Gawd, I learned that stuff when I was 12 and that was many years ago when we couldn't even afford a calculator.

Comment: well the way how my function works is if they pick a check the shipping and handling fee is 0, then if they pick paypal they get the grandtotal *.045, and i only mentioned subtotal because i wasnt sure if i can add that variable in there. - my main purpose of the question is when they pick paypal how can i have the if statement of the shipping and handling fee be added to the grandtotal.

Comment: @user2705751 I could easily give you the answer, but then you wouldn't have learned anything. All you need to do is think of the way it's going to get processed. Define what the base price is and assign it to a variable. After determine what your potential shipping rate will be and assign a variable to that. Once you've gotten all that, you can just add both variables together in your `if` statement, or just one number in an `else` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a line after displaying the Shipping & Handling fees that increase the grandtotal according:

```
if ($PAYMETHOD == $paypal)
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = ".($GRANDTOTAL * .045);
    $GRANDTOTAL = $GRANDTOTAL * 1.045;
}
    elseif ($PAYMETHOD == $check)
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = 0";
}
```

Comment: well the way how my function works is if they pick a check the shipping and handling fee is 0, then if they pick paypal they get the grandtotal *.045, so if i add $GRANDTOTAL = $GRANDTOTAL * .045; will that affect when someone clicks the check option?

Comment: If you add the line inside the ($PAYMETHOD == $paypal) condition block, the $GRANDTOTAL variable will be modified only for paypal payments. Please note that the right formula is the one inside my reply (multiply by 1.045, not 0.045) otherwise your $GRANDTOTAL variable will contain only the Shipping & Handling fees...

Comment: why would it be 1.045 if u dont mind me asking?

Comment: If you have, for example, a $GRANTOTAL that is 100, multipling it by 0.045 will result in 4.5 that is the amount of Shipping & Handling fees, but you want that your $GRANDTOTAL will be 100+4.5, so multipling by 1.045 will do the trick, it gives you 104.5.

Comment: @user2705751 That is exactly what I had in mind. The `1.045` is this: An item is `1` which is the base unit number when multiplying a whole number, then comes the percentage or decimal. Again, basic accounting/business stuff. *"You learned absolutely nothing"*, and that's why you're still asking questions, and will keep on asking questions till you figure things out for yourself. I never use a calculator btw.